# Install phpcs sublime text 2 yields OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: sublimetext2

I just installed phpcs via package manager on sublime text 2. When I go to tools-->sniff this file I get this error in the console:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 362, in run_
  File "./phpcs.py", line 599, in run
  File "./phpcs.py", line 424, in run
  File "./phpcs.py", line 139, in get_errors
  File "./phpcs.py", line 215, in execute
  File "./phpcs.py", line 218, in parse_report
  File "./phpcs.py", line 169, in shell_out
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What does the error mean? If I run `python --version` I see 2.7.5. Maybe there is some issue because it is looking in /Versions/2.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the `Phpcs` plugin cannot find either your `php` binary, or your `phpcs` binary. For example, if you used MacPorts, they are probably installed in `/opt/local/bin`, while Homebrew should have installed it in `/usr/local/bin` (I think, I haven't used HB in a long time). First, open Terminal and type `which php` and `which phpcs`, then copy down the paths.

Next, in Sublime, select **`Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> PHP Code Sniffer -> Settings-Default`**. Copy the entire contents of the file, then open **`Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> PHP Code Sniffer -> Settings-User`** (which should be empty) and paste the contents into it. You can now close the Default Settings, as that file should never be modified for any ST2 plugins - put any changes into a User Settings file. Now, in the Settings-User File, scroll down to line 64 and put the full path to `phpcs` between the empty quotes, like this:

```js
"phpcs_executable_path": "/opt/local/bin/phpcs",
```

If the path to the `php` binary was something ***other*** than `/usr/bin/php`, then scroll up to line 36 and put the full path in between the empty quotes:

```js
"phpcs_php_prefix_path": "/opt/local/bin/php",
```

and that should be it. Save the file, restart Sublime, and try the "Sniff" command again. The reason it's not finding your installed executables, even though you can run them in Terminal (hopefully), is because the `PATH` for programs launched from Finder or the Dock is different than the `PATH` set in Terminal in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` or what have you. If you're a Mac power user and want to change the default path seen by applications, check out my answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89076/19512) over at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: that solved it. thanks. Now console is showing "ApplySyntax: Syntax already set to Packages/PHP/PHP.tmLanguage" but that is a different issue I suppose